# Different field values for each user

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    art_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    plu_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)

    sales_price_brutto = models.FloatField(null=True)
    sales_price_netto = models.FloatField(null=True)
    last_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    purchase_price_brutto = models.FloatField(null=True)
    purchase_price_netto = models.FloatField(null=True)             
    entry_date = models.DateField()
    margin = models.FloatField(null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I created for example two user groups. Then I want to each group of users have different values in stock and sales_price_brutto (save method of model calculate rest of the fields values depending on sales_price_brutto and purchase_price_brutto). I tried adding one more field:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(Group, editable=False)
```

But it seems to not work as I want. I don't really know if there is a way to do that.

Comment: "It seems to not work" is not enough information. What happens - is there an error? What is the error? What did you expect to happen?

Also if you are calculating other fields from the information given you should not (normally) be saving them to the database. This is called denormalisation and makes it harder to ensure the information is consistent. Instead make these fields methods on the Product model.

Comment: Error is 'not null constraint failed', but I assume I have 1000 of Product objects and in all of it I want to share every field between users except stock which must be individual for each user.

Comment: Probably you did not set an owner before saving the object. Your snippet above does not include `null=True` for `owner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `stock` field to depend on the user then you need to have another model to contain that information. It might look something like:

```
class UserStock(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

You would then not have a `stock` field on the `Product` model but create and save one of these objects to set up the per-user stock information. You might have to change the name if your user model is not called `User`.

Remember that database tables (which is what you are creating with a django model) store a 2D array of data. You can't easily (and shouldn't) try to put several bits of data in a single field.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like inventory/sales and you want to show different customers different prices, or something roughly equivalent.  This cannot be accomplished in one table as you are trying to do.

The standard way to do this is with price books.  Each price book is defined for a list of customer numbers and is a list of products/prices.

Another approach I have seen is to set up pricing "zones" where each customer is assigned to a given "zone" and the price for each zone is calculated from a formula based on the cost.  An example might be that zone 1 is cost * 1.25, zone 2 is cost * 1.30, zone 4 is cost * 1.4, and zone 5 is cost * 1.5.  Each customer sees the price for their zone.